# Convert YYYYMMDD filename to YYYYJD

Tags: python, python-2.7, time, julian-date

I'm trying to write a python script to convert a folder of .asc files (365 files for every year in different folders organized by year) that have the yearmonthdate in their filename to have the yearjuliandate instead and the julian date needs to be 3 digits (ie 1 = 001). 
The format they are in: ETos19810101.asc. 
I want them to be as: ETos1981001.asc

How do I write this in Python where I can iterate over each file and convert it to the correct julian day?

I'm trying to write a Python script to convert a folder of .asc files (365 files for every year in different folders organized by year) that have the yearmonthdate in their filename to have the yearjuliandate instead and the julian date needs to be 3 digits (ie 1 = 001).

- The format they are in: `ETos19810101.asc`
- I want them to be as: `ETos1981001.asc`

How do I write this in Python where I can iterate over each file and convert it to the correct julian day?

I have this so far:

```
import os.path, os, glob

for filename in glob.glob(filepath + "/*.asc"):
    jdate = '%03d' %doy #creates 3 digit julian date
    doy = doy + 1
    filename.replace(int[-8:-4], jdate + 1)
```

Comment: Please add any relevant code or error messages to your question by using the edit link.

Comment: I added the code I have so far to my post. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `'%j specifier` along with `datetime.strptime` and `os.rename` and the various `os.path` commands:

```
from datetime import datetime
from glob import glob
import os

for filename in glob(os.path.join(filepath, 'ETos*.asc')):
    try:
        dt = datetime.strptime(os.path.basename(filename), 'ETos%Y%m%d.asc')
    except ValueError as e:
        continue # rest of file name didn't have valid date - do the needful
    os.rename(filename, os.path.join(filepath, format(dt, 'ETos%Y%j.asc')))
```

You'll probably want a bit of handling around that and adjust to take into account your path, but that's the general principle.

Comment: Nice! Thank you, that worked! Don't completely understand how it worked yet (i'm a Python newb) but it worked!

Comment: @MattS no worries have a read through the docs for `os.path.basename` and `datetime.strptime` and `os.path.join` - all should  become more clear than I can summarise without just copy pasting in docs :)

Answer (score 1):

Given a file name as following (you can iterate your file system with `os.walk`)

```
filename = 'ETos19810101.asc'
```

First of all you have to split the filename to get every significant parts:

```
import os
name, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
prefix = name[0:-6] # negative prefix => string end as reference
strdate = name[-6:]
```

Then you can parse the date:

```
from datetime import datetime
date = datetime.strptime(strdate, '%Y%m%d')
```

Now you are able to join everything together (`%Y%j` format the date the way you want):

```
newfilename = '{prefix}{date:%Y%j}{ext}'.format(prefix=prefix, date=date, ext=ext)
```

Finally rename the file:

```
os.rename(filename, newfilename)
```

Note that the last instruction will fail if `newfilename` already exists.
To fix this issue you have to remove the file, if it exists:

```
if os.path.exists(newfilename):
    os.remove(newfilename)
os.rename(filename, newfilename)
```

Answer (score 0):

For working with dates you should use the [`datetime` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html). Parse the date string with `strptime`. There's no function to return a julian date, but it's easy to create one:

```
def julian_day(dt):
    jan1 = dt.replace(month=1, day=1)
    return 1 + (dt - jan1).days
```

Comment: *There's no function to return a julian date* - Well... there's the `strftime` format of `%Y%j` which works fine

Comment: @JonClements yeah, I forgot about that one. There still might be value in getting it as an integer though.